# Does there exist an infinite sequence of positive integers such that the product of any consecutive terms of the sequence is divisible by their sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Does there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of  positive integers, which is not ultimately constant,  such that $\sum_{k=0}^ma_{n+k}|\prod_{k=0}^ma_{n+k} , \forall m,n \in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: At least gp's can't work, ap's can work if $a^{2}$ is divisible by $2a+d$  ($a, d$ are obviously integer).

Comment: Can you please tell me the source of this problem?

Comment: Why the condition "not ultimately constant"? If there were a such a sequence that is eventually constant $=a$, then $ma\mid a^m$ for all $m$, in particular for some prime $m>a$, contradiction.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : Very true ... perhaps I was just being extra cautious ..